# Исключить из выборки

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня запрос, который возвращает вот такой результат:

```
name  | value  |  integer
------------------------
sacha |      1 |     NULL
oleg  |   NULL |     NULL
------------------------
```

Какое условие можно записать в `WHERE` чтобы исключить из результата строки с `NULL` в обеих полях?

Comment: `... and (value is not null or integer is not null)` . [Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285448/mysql-select-only-not-null-values) , [Man](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: @nobody Большое спасибо! Вы в решение напишите. Т.е. напишите как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table_name where (value is not null or integer is not null)
```

Comment: только увидел что ответ был дан ранее в комменте...

Comment: и поэтому у тебя также стоят скобочки, ну-да ну-да.. :D

Comment: А как по другому? при добавлени любого другого условия ... and ... без скобок что получится? (я изначально написал  в конце and ... другие условия) но потом стёр. А вообще напиши ты ответ, и автор уверен его пометит как ответ, и я добавлю свой +, ты по любому первый был.. )))